# Showing calendar exactly below a textbox

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I designed a dropdown calendar but if I click on the Image to show the drop down calendar,I cant see that, below the Textbox. how can I show this calendar exactly below the textbox:

```
<table width=100%>
  <tr align=center>
    <td align=center>
      <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" GroupingText="Suche" >
        <table width=100%>
          <tr align=center>
            <td align=center>
              <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Von :"></asp:Label>
              <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
              <img id="Calimg1" src="Images/cal.jpg" onclick="selectdate()" />
              <div id="calblock1" class=calander >
                <asp:Calendar OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged"
                              ID="Calendar1" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFFCC" 
                              BorderColor="#FFCC66" BorderWidth="1px"
                              DayNameFormat="Shortest" Font-Names="Verdana"
                              Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#663399" Height="200px" 
                              ShowGridLines="True" Width="220px">
                  <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True"
                                  Height="1px" />
                  <NextPrevStyle Font-Size="9pt" ForeColor="#FFFFCC" />
                  <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#CC9966" />
                  <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCFF" Font-Bold="True" />
                  <SelectorStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" />
                  <TitleStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True"
                              Font-Size="9pt" ForeColor="#FFFFCC" />
                  <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="White" />
                </asp:Calendar>
              </div>
              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"
                                          runat="server" 
                                          ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
                                          ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red">
              </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
          </tr>
......
```

CSS:

```
.calander
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute
}
```

and the JavaScript that I used:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Calimg1').click(function () {
            if (isAnyVisible()) return false;
            $('#calblock1').slideToggle("slow");
        });

        $('#Img1').click(function () {
            if (isAnyVisible()) return false;
            $('#Div2').slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });

    function isAnyVisible() {
        if ($('#Calimg1').is(':visible') || $('#Img1').is(':visible')) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: how do you expect us to run the server side code, just provide the generated html..

Comment: I see it hier somehow correct http://jsfiddle.net/tYcfQ/ but If I run it in my browser not

Comment: It works in the fiddle because your viewport is so small. `position:absolute` implies... position, yet you give no `top` or `left` -- no position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've specified that the `position` is `absolute`, which is the right track. However, you're missing a few things.

First, the parent of an absolute element should have `position:relative`. Without that relative parent, when you specify a `top` and `left` it will be relative to the entire document. Much easier to work with if the coordinates you're using are relative to the container.

Next, nested tables are horrible. Use divs, eliminate some of those containers. CSS positioning, floats, margins, and padding will accomplish the same result.

**Documention**

- CSS `position` at MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position
- A list apart article about CSS positioning - http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/
- Stop using tables for layout @ Stack Overflow - [Why not use tables for layout in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

There is a better using **native .Net** tools if you have 2012 or later.
Use **any textbox**, then go to properties and change the **TextMode** to **DateTimeLocal**. That will create a very nice dropdown calendar. Note: If your IE is too old it won't show the calendar, so try debug it on Chrome and Firefox too.